# celerybeat how to pass arguments via scheduler to functions?

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

im having trouble passing arguments to my functions via celerybeat schedule. After searching it looks as though I should be able to pass them with the args command but im getting errors as per the below. can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'maintenance_mail_1_day': {
        'task': 'home.tasks.maintenance_mail',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='15'),
        'args' : (1),
    },
    'maintenance_mail_3_day': {
        'task': 'home.tasks.maintenance_mail',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='15'),
        'args' : (3),
    },    
    'maintenance_mail_5_day': {
        'task': 'home.tasks.maintenance_mail',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='15'),
        'args' : (5),
    },
    'maintenance_mail_7_day': {
        'task': 'home.tasks.maintenance_mail',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='15'),
        'args' : (7),
    }
```

tasks,py

```
@app.task
def maintenance_mail(days):
    return send_maintnance_emails(days)
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Args must be a tuple:  do `'args' : (1,)` (note the extra comma)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following holds in Python: `(1) == 1`

In order to make it a singleton `tuple`, add an extra comma: `(1,)` and in your settings accordingly:

```
# ...
'args' : (1,),
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the arguments and keyword arguments used to execute the task as follows. Note how JSON serialization is required.

```
import json

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'maintenance_mail_1_day': {
        'task': 'home.tasks.maintenance_mail',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='15'),
        'args' : json.dumps([1]),
    }
}
```

OR

```
import json

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'maintenance_mail_1_day': {
        'task': 'home.tasks.maintenance_mail',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='15'),
        'kwargs' : json.dumps({
            'days': 1,
        }),
    }
}
```

More info here: [django-celery-beat documentation](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: The docs you link to are for `django-celery-beat` talking about adding rows into the table.  The config that OP mentioned requires `'args'` to be a tuple or a list and `'kwargs'` to be a dict:  https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#available-fields